# Change linker order in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I have a project in DialogBlocks 5.03 that compiles fine with mingw32, but using CodeBlocks 13.12 show this error:

```
F:\wxWidgets-3.0.0\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30u_core.a(corelib_msw_listctrl.o):listctrl.cpp:(.text+0x1019): undefined reference to `ImageList_GetImageCount@4'
F:\wxWidgets-3.0.0\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30u_core.a(corelib_msw_listctrl.o):listctrl.cpp:(.text+0x1063): undefined reference to `ImageList_Draw@24'
F:\wxWidgets-3.0.0\lib\gcc_lib/libwxmsw30u_core.a(corelib_msw_listctrl.o):listctrl.cpp:(.text+0x108c): undefined reference to `ImageList_GetIconSize@12'
```

I have detected that is the linker order of the libraries, in DialogBlocks this is the library order:

`-Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lwxmsw30u_xrc -lwxmsw30u_richtext -lwxmsw30u_aui -lwxmsw30u_html -lwxmsw30u_stc -lwxmsw30u_propgrid -lwxmsw30u_ribbon -lwxmsw30u_adv -lwxmsw30u_core -lwxbase30u -lwxbase30u_net -lwxbase30u_xml -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32`

And it compiles successfully

In CodeBlocks this is the compiler library order:

`-mthreads -s -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--subsystem,windows  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -lwxscintilla -lwxmsw30u_xrc -lwxmsw30u_richtext -lwxmsw30u_aui -lwxmsw30u_html -lwxmsw30u_stc -lwxmsw30u_propgrid -lwxmsw30u_ribbon -lwxmsw30u_adv -lwxmsw30u_core -lwxbase30u -lwxbase30u_net -lwxbase30u_xml -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat -mwindows`

If I compile the CodeBlocks project from command line using the DialogBlocks linker options, it compiles successfully

So in the CodeBlocks menu: Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings, I add the libraries in the order that I want but CodeBlocks adds the parameters in its own order, even repeating the libraries

How I change the order?

Comment: looks like it is the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600529/how-do-i-set-up-the-linking-order-in-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sandro I found the answer

I have CodeBlocks 13.12, to change the linker params you must go to the menu:

> Settings -> Compiler -> Tab: Other settings -> Click button: Advanced
>   options... -> It shows a message box warning, click: Yes -> In the
>   Command ComboBox select: Link object files to execute, and change
>   this:

`$linker $libdirs -o $exe_output $link_objects $link_resobjects $link_options $libs -mwindows`

to:

`$linker $libdirs -o $exe_output $link_objects $link_resobjects $link_options`

> Click button: OK

Then go to menu:

> Project -> Build options... -> Tab: Linker settings -> In: Other linker
>   options, I added my own ordered libs

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can't agree with the topic above, because it is only partially solution. I guess that better will be set the order of libraries in individual compiler/linker settings for individual project. Code::Blocks is offering Append or Prepend order of Linker options within project settings.

For linker In Code::Blocks IDE you can change the order of the command line parameters. The settings where you can do this is in the compiler options for specific project. Right click for the project tree, Build Options -> Linker Settings -> Policy: Prepend or Append target options to project options. This will solve issue of wrong order and unsuccessful linking in GCC linker. There is not necessary to change the order or remove parameters explicitly in global settings as described in previous topic.