# how to link against wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, wxwidgets

So i downloaded the newest version of wxPack, coming with version 3.0.0 of wxWidgets, and tried linking against it in a simple C++ application build in/with Code::Blocks. No matter what libaries i link against or in what order they are, i ALWAYS get undefined symbol errors.
the only library files of wxWidgets i need are `libwxbase30u` and `libwxmsw30u_core`, as i only show a wxMessageBox for testing issues. Some guy at this question here provided me with a possible solution, but it didnt work. i tried linking against several windows libaries already, because when linking in specific orders the undefined symbols were all windows related ([Link to my older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495303/link-correctly-against-wxwidgets)), like `iid_ishelllink`.
the closest i got to a solution was by linking against dozens of windows libraries first and then against `libwxbase30u` and then `libwxmsw30u_core`. though i dont get why the error from `shell32` was still there, as i linked against it beforehand. Btw, the compiler im using is the 32bit version of the TDM-GCC-Compiler on Windows 8.1 64bit. Any more info needed is probably in my older question, which was left unanswered. Now, i only want to know EVERY library i need to link against, and in what order, in order to get my program to work. with a freshly installed/compiled version of wxWidgets.

Comment: One of those tutorials lists exactly the libraries you need to link and how to set up the compiler.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tried those already, as i said. still no success.

Comment: This also happened to me, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749643/change-linker-order-in-codeblocks)

Answer (score 0):

A beginner's quick reference for setting up wxWidgets with Code::Blocks in Windows

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=WxWindowsQuickRef